# Django Error in Post Request: 'module' object has no attribute 'POST'

Tags: python, django, post, request, django-views

Hello i have a login method in views.py then if i call it from form with post request i have 'module' object has no attribute 'POST' error but as you see i can get form values in traceback. I got form values like that in my before django project. I compared between my old code and this code but i couldn't find my mistake.

[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: -1 for posting screenshots. Everything you have posted is text, and could be much more easily posted by simply cutting and pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [definition of a django view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/):

> A view function, or view for short, is simply a Python function that
>   takes a Web request and returns a Web response.

`request` should be passed to the view as an argument, not imported:

```
def loginUser(request):
    ...
```

And remove `from django.http import *` line.

Comment: Problem is solved. But i have one more question. I will code my login system with my old habits from asp.net or php. I will get email and password values then control them in database and i will start user session.  Is it true?

Comment: You should refer this (http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html) chapter from How to Tango with Django to get an idea.

Comment: @MertSaygı Good. Take a look at the [Authenticating Users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users) documentation paragraph. Also, there are a lot of tutorials and blog posts about building login pages, e.g. http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/login.html

Comment: @praba230890 I was pasting the link while you were posting the comment :) Nice timing.

Comment: I saw this method but this method needs a login view like "url(r'^login/$', views.user_login, name='login')," but i have login form in top of every page. What should i do?